# Converting OS Master Map Topography in QGIS

Tags: qgis, os-mastermap

I am extremely new to QGIS (installed hours ago) to try and convert the OS Master Map Topography.  Everything I have found recently has been years old and tools have moved on.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to use the .gz file from OS with QGIS so I can output a file that will be used in MapInfo?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add the GZ file into Qgis.  Is it detailed on this page ([https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/qgis/importing_mastermap/using_standard_qgis_tools.htm#:~:text=QGIS%20will%20read%20GML%20directly,view%20the%20data%20in%20QGIS.&text=in%20the%20Manage%20Layers%20toolbar,to%20import%20and%20press%20Open.](https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/webhelp/digimapgis/qgis/importing_mastermap/using_standard_qgis_tools.htm#:%7E:text=QGIS%20will%20read%20GML%20directly,view%20the%20data%20in%20QGIS.&text=in%20the%20Manage%20Layers%20toolbar,to%20import%20and%20press%20Open.)) I also included screen shots below along with the steps to export to TAB files for Mapinfo.

Layer Menu -> Add layer -> Add Vector Layer
[image: add vector layer]

Click the three dots and pick the GZ file, make sure you are viewing all files i the open dialog box.
[image: picked gz file]

Click Add button and then select all layers and then OK.
[image: layer select]

You can then export each layer to a TAB file so it can be importer into Mapinfo.

Right click layer -> Export -> Save Features As... -> Pick Mapinfo tab format, pick filename, click Ok.
[image: export map info]